# Is the configuration correct? I'm not getting value from server

Tags: java, angularjs, xml, spring, spring-mvc

Angular
I'm using **Java at Backend - Spring MVC FrameWork - AngularJS at Frontend.**

I couldn't achieve server side hit in this case. 
The control goes to the catch block and doesn't return the string.
I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I'm new to angular and spring. I've no idea on the configuration for integrating the front end and the backend.

The following scripts and java file are:

SpringSample.java :

```
public class SpringSample {   
    @RestController
    public class SampleClass {

        @RequestMapping(value="/sampleData" , method = RequestMethod.GET, 
                produces = {"application/json"})
        public String getStringValue(){
            return "Hi Hello World! Good Morning";
        }
    }  
}
```

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>AngularJS</title>
<script
    src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js">
</script>
    <script> 
var demo = angular.module('demo', []);
demo.controller('Hello', function ($scope, $http, $location) {
    var url = $location.absUrl();
    console.log(url);
    $http.get('http://localhost:8084/AngularSpringMVCSample' + '/sampleData').
            success(function (response) {
                $scope.greeting = response.data;
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            }).catch(
            console.log("ERROR")
            );
});
    </script>    

</head>
<body ng-app="demo">
    <div ng-controller="Hello">
            <p>The ID is {{greeting}}</p>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

context.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/AngularSpringMVCSample"/>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <!--
    Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
    for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
    define an explicit mapping for it.
    -->
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".html" />

    <!--
    The index controller.
    -->
    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />

</beans>
```

Please educate me on how to go forward in this simple code. I'm working for past 2-3 hrs on this. What modifications are need to be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you call RestController endpoint using something like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or `CURL` and get the `Hi Hello World! Good Morning` value in return?

Comment: No, I haven't checked that. Btw, what is that? Is that a tool?

Comment: It is, you can make request to servers urls to see how they behave. Just like your browser. Except you can decide what headers you want to send and so on. It will let you know what exact error the server throws as well.

Comment: Okay, fine. What url should I provide and test? I guess there are separate urls for server and the UI side. am I right?

Comment: You need to call this endpoint `/sampleData`. By default the server most of spring mvc have `localhost:8080` as default. Unless you've change the port when you spinning the server

Comment: Also, The latest version of AngularJS, which is in maintenance mode, is 1.6.x. Why are you using such an old 1.2.x version? Have you looked in the console? In the network panel of the browser dev tools? You need to at least *know* what happens.

Comment: I have changed that version from 1.2 to 1.6x. Still facing the same issue buddy.